# Ошибка пайтон при использование библиотеки pytube

Tags: python, pytube

```
from pytube import YouTube

link = input("Enter link:")
YT=YouTube(link)
YT.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
print("Successfull")
```

Запускаю и:

```
& C:/Users/nikit/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe d:/Python/Projects/PlaylistsDownloader.py
Enter link:https://youtu.be/Du2MUFuGnsI
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Projects\PlaylistsDownloader.py", line 4, in <module>
    YT=YouTube(link)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in prefetch
    self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 36, in get
    return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 24, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request)  # nosec
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 557, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 749, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone
```

Comment: Обновите версию pytube

Answer (score 1):

Вы получили ошибку 410 из YouTube сервера.

Эта ошибка значит, что вами заданный адрес показывает на ресурс, *который существовал, но уже не существует* (потому что он был удален, перенесенный, переименованный и т. д.).

*Примечание:*

В отличие от ошибки 404, сервер знает, что в прошлом этот адрес был правильным.

Comment: «Это математик! — Как вы об этом узнали? — Только у математика мог быть такой абсолютно точный и абсолютно бесполезный ответ.»